# Twilio WhatsApp+MS Botframework

Tags: twilio, botframework, whatsapp

Can anyone please guide me how to integrate Twilio WhatsApp with MS Bot framework.I have a Microsoft bot deployed on Azure. I have configure the endpoint in Twilio dashboard .I am using the twilo whatsapp (adapter for MS bot(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@botbuildercommunity/adapter-twilio-whatsapp ). it seems to be not working. Please help

Comment: Please provide some code, what you have tried so far. The error you are receiving when you say "not working". Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the cpmment. I was able to write an Azure Function App( MS Bot) and connect to Twilio sandbox for WhatsApp.